# Вчерашний день. Лучше не использовать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вчерашний день - это день, который был вчера. Но день, который был вчера - это и есть вчера.
Значит, вчерашний день, то есть вчера, это день, который был вчера. Вчера, которое было вчера.
Вчерашний хлеб - еще могу понять.
Я прав в рассуждении и это масло масляное или все иначе?

Comment: Тут вопрос в том, может ли быть вчера существительным или только лишь наречием. Ответ может. Например: Вчера было холодным.

Comment: То есть: 1) Вчера - день, предшествовавший сегодняшнему дню; 2) Вчерашний - нечто, что было вчера; 3) Вчерашний (иначе) - нечто, что было в день, предшествовавший сегодняшнему дню; 4) Вчерашний день - день, который был в день, предшествовавший сегодняшнему дню. Вот это меня и смущает, день, который был в день.

Comment: Да, избыточная формулировка: День который был в день, который был в день, который был в день, ...

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не совсем правы.

1. Из словаря:

**ВЧЕРА**, I. **нареч.** 1. **В день,** предшествовавший сегодняшнему дню; накануне. Виделись в. Сегодня жарко, но не так, как в. 2. В недавнем прошлом. Ещё в. он был студентом, и вот уже - учитель.
II. неизм.; ср. День, предшествовавший сегодняшнему. Назначили встречу на в., а он не пришёл.

**ВЧЕРАШНИЙ**, 1. Происходивший, бывший, сделанный и т.п. вчера. В. разговор. В. дождь. В-ие щи. **В. день** (также: прошлое, прошедшее; устарелое, несовременное).

2. Вчера – это **временное наречие**, оно отвечает на вопрос "когда" и является обстоятельством. А вчерашний день имеет **предметное значение**, в предложении может быть дополнением, подлежащим.

Например: *Да и весь вчерашний день ― цепь ошибок и заблуждений*. [Анатолий Азольский. Лопушок // «Новый Мир», 1998]

Или: *Вчера был хороший день.  Вчерашний день был хорошим.* Здесь семантика одинаковая, но грамматика совершенно разная. Поэтому мы не можем обойтись без сочетания "вчерашний день".

3. Но однокоренные слова нежелательно использовать в одном предложении, например: *Всё это было вчера, поэтому не надо жить вчерашним днем.*
4. Предметное значение у слова "вчера" тоже есть (несклоняемое сущ. ср. рода), но оно используется реже, например: Забудь о вчера (о вчерашнем дне). Это скорее разговорный стиль.

Comment: Вчера это существительное, а не разговорный стиль. Множество словарей это фиксируют без пометок. Из словаря: вчера=существительное. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#:~:text=%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%2C,%2D%20%5B%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%201996%5D.

Comment: И здесь тоже
https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/vchera.html#:~:text=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%C2%AB%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%C2%BB%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F,%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5.

Comment: http://nskhuman.ru/unislov/slovar.php?nslovo=12533

Comment: Вы не совсем внимательны, к сожалению. Разве я говорила о стилевых пометках в словарях? У Кузнецова нет такой пометки. Я говорила о ЧАСТОТНОСТИ применения «вчера» в качестве существительного.  Не для каждого случая это слово подходит, и я привела пример, который показался мне разговорным. Ваше же предложение  (Вчера было холодным) я бы тоже не отнесла к нейтральному стилю (даже затрудняюсь сказать, какой стиль здесь у вас). Сочетание «в недавнем вчера» выглядит немного устаревшим, но такие варианты  иногда подходят для романтического стиля. Но это все мое личное восприятие.

Comment: А разве я где-то говорил, что вы где-то говорили об этом? Мой комментарий касается возможного вашего намека на это, но не ваших фактических слов.

Comment: У вас нормальный ответ от меня +. Просто уточнил во избежание двусмысленности, что это не не РАЗГОВОРНОЕ по словарям.

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше одобрение для меня особенно ценно. Когда-то мы с вами дружили, помнится...